# How to get all $_POST[] data from a randomly generated <form>

Tags: php, forms, post

I generate several forms with different `<input>` name attributes and I can not exactly define all input-names for fetching them after posting.

How can I receive ALL `$_POST` data from the form (without having a name-attribute) and put them in an array like that:

```
'name_attribute' => 'value'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic loop will do this:

```
$post = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $post[$key] = $value;
}
```

I don't know how this benefits you though as all you have done is remake your `$_POST` superglobal.

Comment: Can't you just: $yourvarialbe = $_POST; ??

Comment: Thanks, I use it because my platform allows users to customize their forms and as I don't want to add each input-attribute into the database this way is kinda easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$post = $_POST;
foreach($post as $name => $value)
{
  echo $name." = ".$value;
}
```

Comment: why -1 for my answer. I don't know why? I just posted my method. Just assign the POST to a variable and using in foreach. Some black-cheep putting downvote for my answer even he/she lost their reputation.

Answer (score 0):

With any POSTs, php puts it into the array $_POST. You can treat this like any array and just loop through each key/value of the POST.

```
$your_array = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val){
    $your_array[$key] = $val;
}
```

to make this more secure, I would suggested escaping the $val by using other php functions such as [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is an associative array in the format

```
'field_name' => 'field_value'
```